# update data dynamically using Modal in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

Tomorrow I am presenting my code in sprint. Everything was working fine until a few hours ago. I have a modal which pops up when a user clicks on Edit. It *was* giving the values according to `id`.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                @foreach($Community as $editCommunity)
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit: {!! $editCommunity->community_name !!}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-group" action="/update/{{$editCommunity->id}}" method="post" id="editCommunityForm">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <input type="text" name="community_name" class="form-control" value="{{$editCommunity->community_name}}">
                </form>
                @endforeach
                <button class="btn btn-custom dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" form="editCommunityForm">Update Community</button><br /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                {{--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>--}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am very upset and confused and don't know what to do.

Any help would highly be appreciated

[image: See this image to get proper understanding]

**Edit:**
After reading the comments; i have understood that only one `id` would be updated every time. How could i change the `id` dynamically and update data of that specific `id` and each time it should get only `clicked id`.

**Controller Function to update:**

```
 public function updateCommunity($id, CommunityRequest $request) {
        $updateCommunity = Community::findOrFail($id);
        $updateCommunity->update($request->all());
        return back();
    }
```

**View Buttons:**

```
@foreach ($Community as $communities)
     <tr>
        <td>{{$communities->community_name}}</td>
        <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit</button>
        | <a href="{{ URL::to('delete', array($communities->id)) }}" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: note: your're dumping out multiple `<form>` with the **SAME** `id`, which is illegal. `id`s must be unique across the entire document.

Comment: it was working fine. according to my understanding, foreach is used to provide unique `id` every time button of `field` is clicked. It is storing the data fine. it deleting `data` on the basis of `id`

Comment: no, it's not giving a unique id: `id="editCommunityForm"` there's NOTHING "dynamic" or "unique" about that. the same id will be output for every iteration of the loop. and since your submit button specifically targets that specific id name, you'll only ever submit the first form on the page - since IDs must be unique, there's no point in searching the rest of the page for more once one's been found.

Comment: what should i do now? My Team Lead said me to do it in this way. How could i manage it get unique `id` for every occurrence. thanks

Comment: if your team lead told you to use the same id everywhere, then, frankly, your team lead is an idiot. worst case, you can always just have a counter loop and add that to each id, so you generate `id1`, `id2`, `id3`, etc...

Comment: nope he had not told to use same `id` He said whenever user clicks on edit button. updating should be done in modal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

I understand you have all the communities listed in a list somewhere outside this modal, each entry has an edit and delete button. Upon clicking edit button user should be presented a modal with a single form to edit community he clicked that button for. All this using a single modal element.

The fact that you don't want to use more than one modal means you want to generate less DOM in order to provide faster loading times, if that's the case then edit your view buttons.

```
@foreach ($Community as $communities)
     <tr>
        <td>{{$communities->community_name}}</td>
        <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-community="{{ json_encode($communities) }}">Edit</button>
        | <a href="{{ URL::to('delete', array($communities->id)) }}" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
@endforeach
```

Notice new `data-community` attribute in edit button.

Now change your modal to provide a template for community edit form instead of providing a form for each community.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit: <span></span></h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-group" method="post" id="editCommunityForm">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <input type="text" name="community_name" class="form-control">
                </form>
                <button class="btn btn-custom dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" form="editCommunityForm">Update Community</button><br /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                {{--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>--}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now what you need to do it listen to edit community button click event (the one from view buttons), get `data-community` object from it, open a modal and fill with to fit edited community.

- search for `$('modal-title span')` and `.html()` community name into it
- search for `$('#editCommunityForm')` and change it's action to `\update\{community_id}`
- search for `$('button[form="editCommunityForm"])` and on click send form using ajax

There are many other ways to do this, better ways, it's just a simple example on how you can make it work.

---

**Original answer**

How come your submit button is outside of `foreach` but in an image it is displayed after each form? Also you are closing `<div>` tag in a loop that you opened before that loop.

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    @foreach($Community as $editCommunity)
    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit: {!! $editCommunity->community_name !!}</h4>
</div> // You are closing a tag opened before foreach loop
<div class="modal-body">
    <form class="form-group" action="/update/{{$editCommunity->id}}" method="post" id="editCommunityForm">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <input type="text" name="community_name" class="form-control" value="{{$editCommunity->community_name}}">
    </form>
    @endforeach
    <button class="btn btn-custom dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" form="editCommunityForm">Update Community</button><br /><br />
</div>
```

After you fix this you can simply edit form id by adding `$editCommunity->id` to it, like so:

```
 <form class="form-group" action="/update/{{$editCommunity->id}}" method="post" id="editCommunityForm_{{$editCommunity->id}}">
```

Then you can edit button's form parameter to match your form:

```
<button class="btn btn-custom dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" form="editCommunityForm_{{$editCommunity->id}}">Update Community</button>
```

You should end up with this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @foreach($Community as $editCommunity)
                <h4 class="modal-title">Edit: {!! $editCommunity->community_name !!}</h4>
                <form class="form-group" action="/update/{{$editCommunity->id}}" method="post" id="editCommunityForm_{{$editCommunity->id}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                    <input type="text" name="community_name" class="form-control" value="{{$editCommunity->community_name}}">
                </form>
                <button class="btn btn-custom dropdown-toggle waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" form="editCommunityForm_{{$editCommunity->id}}">Update Community</button><br /><br />
                @endforeach
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                {{--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>--}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is updating the `data` of every community, But it shows all the `communities` in the `modal` at the same time. How could this problem be solved ? Thanks @Linek

Comment: @QasimAli If I get it right you want to show all the communities in the modal but update one at the time, my approach does just that provided that you have your javascript in place to handle submit buttons as you've placed them outside forms. Also you probably don't want to reload on each update do you?

Comment: Yes, you had pointed some valuable things. But i dont want to show all the communities on the `modal`. I just want to show `only that` community against which the `Edit button` is fired. Which means if i click on `id=7, edit button` it should only show the `id=7` value not all. At this time it is showing all the entries. If i have 20 entries. `modal` would have 20 forms in it. i dont want it in that way.

Comment: @QasimAli I updated my answer, is it what you are trying to do?